# Add comment to file while opening (C)

Tags: shell

I have output from static analyzer, that I parsed with Bash.

Now I want Vim to run on specified by analyzer line and add comment containing  warning id and description.

I tried this,

```sh
vim $file +$line+'normal A'+'/* KW: $kwid desc: $desc */'
```

Where `$file` is the path to file, `$line` line number, `$kwid` and `$desc` are strings that describe what problem I'm working on for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
vim "$file" +$line +"normal! A/* KW: $your text $here */"
```

Parameter expansion does not happen in single quotes in bash.

Each command given to vim get’s one `+` (it is not like string concatenation at all).

Comment: @filbranden done! Good catch I got lazy typing on mobile (could you tell :P )